# Nested Field Collections + PHP

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a Field Collection called "Tab Content" which contains fields such as title, body, and a nested Field Collection called "Content Sidebar". The idea is that you can enter information that populates into a tabbed interface.

In each of these tabs, there is a sidebar which can contain any number of what I'm calling "callout boxes". The "callout box" fields live within the "Content Sidebar" field collection so the user has the ability to add multiple "callout boxes" per tab. I have everything printing out using the code from here: http://drupal.org/node/1398966 but the problem I'm having is that each tab is printing out every "callout box" when it should only be printing out the ones assigned to that tab.

Screenshot of what happens below. The Second tab is highlighted and displaying all the callout boxes when it should only be showing the "Second Tab Callout Box" while the first tab should contain the other two.
[image]

Here is my current code:

```
<div id="tab-content" class="clear-fix">
  <?php foreach ($node->field_tab_content['und'] as $key => $value) {
    $img_val = null;
    $field_collection = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($value['value']));
    $idx = $value['value'];
    $sectiontitle = $field_collection[$idx]->field_section_title['und'][0]['value'];
    $sectioncontent = $field_collection[$idx]->field_section_content['und'][0]['value'];
    $filteredtitle = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $sectiontitle);
    if(!empty($field_collection[$idx]->field_sidebar_image['und'])) {
      $img_val = $field_collection[$idx]->field_sidebar_image['und'][0]['filename'];
    }
    $img_url = $GLOBALS['base_path'] . 'sites/default/files/general/' . $img_val;
  ?>
  <div id="<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $filteredtitle)); ?>">
    <div class="copy-column">
      <?php echo $sectioncontent; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="content-sidebar">
      <?php if ($img_val): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="sidebar image" />
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php //Here is the nested field collection
        $top_level = null;
        $second_level = null;
        foreach ($node->field_tab_content['und'] as $top_level_collection) {
          $top_level = load_collection($top_level_collection['value']);
          if(!empty($top_level->field_content_sidebar['und'] )) {
            foreach ($top_level->field_content_sidebar['und'] as $second_level_collection) {
              $second_level = load_collection($second_level_collection['value']);
              foreach ($second_level->field_callout_box_title['und'] as $callout_title) {
                print "<div class='callout-box'>";
                print '<h4>' . $callout_title['safe_value'] . '</h4>';
              }
              foreach ($second_level->field_callout_box_content['und'] as $callout_content) {
                print "<div class='inner-pad'>" . $callout_content['value']. "</div>";
                print "</div>";
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ?>
    </div><!-- content-sidebar -->
  </div>
<?php }; ?>
</div><!-- tab-content -->
```

Comment: I have never attempted this, so I don't immediately see where the problem is. However, what I do notice is that some better coding practices would make the code a great deal easier to read, and thus debug. I would start with a serious refactoring of the code.

Comment: Instead of ['und'], may I suggest $node->field_name[$node->language]